# Can't delete or splice row from JSON

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I'm trying to remove a user from a blacklist feature. When they remove the user from a list, it should splice/remove that JSON row and update mat-table in angular.

I tried `delete this.blacklistGroupTable[i]`
but that returns the JSON object unaltered.

I also tried
this.blacklistGroupTable.splice(i, 1); , but it says `_this.blacklistGroupTable.splice is not a function`

Why is that?

[image]

```
unblockUser(userId: string, username: string, i: number) {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ConfirmationBlacklistComponent, {
      panelClass: "dialogBoxStyler",
      data: {
        username: username
      }
    });

    dialogRef
      .afterClosed()
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy))
      .subscribe(result => {
        if (result) {
          alert("I: " + i);
          this.blacklistGroupTable.splice(i, 1);
          //  delete this.blacklistGroupTable[i];
          console.log("this.blacklistGroupTable");
          console.log(this.blacklistGroupTable);
          this.dataSource.data = this.blacklistGroupTable;

          this.submitListingService
            .sendUserToBlacklist(this.userId, this.bidderId, "UNBLOCK")
            .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy))
            .subscribe(res => {
              console.log("res");
              console.log(res);
            });
        } else {
          this.blacklistUserDecision = false;
          return;
        }
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think your `blacklistGroupTable` is not an `array` but a  `FileList`.

A `FileList` is not an `Array`, but it does conform to its contract (has `length` and numeric indices), so we can "borrow" `Array` methods:

try to this to log your files separatly :

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(this.blacklistGroupTable, file => {console.log(file)});
```

and the result of this log : https://postimg.cc/WttmxR60 , means that your `blacklistGroupTable` is a `filelist` of `objects` ! it's no more an `array` , you can delete your elements like this :

```
const files = [...this.blacklistGroupTable['blacklistGroup']]; 
files.splice(i, 1);
```

Comment: I added that line above and did ```file = file.splice(i, 1);``` but got ```ERROR TypeError: "Array.prototype.call is not a function"``` It also says in console ```error TS2339: Property 'call' does not exist on type 'any[]'.``` Also if I do console.log(typeof this.blacklistGroupTable);``` it returns object

Comment: can you try to log `console.log(this.blacklistGroupTable[0]);` and tell me what you get ?

Comment: It says ```undefined```

Comment: it means that your `blacklistGroupTable` is not a table , the problem is not the splice, can i see it's declaration ?

Comment: When you said that I realized somewhat what the issue is. There's another layer called blacklistGroup https://postimg.cc/xcZNDWCb I managed to remove one of the rows using this ```delete this.blacklistGroupTable['blacklistGroup'][i];``` but it says length is 2 and has empty spot. Not really what I was going for. More of a splice would be ideal, but I haven't got that working yet. This doesn't work    ```this.blacklistGroupTable['blacklistGroup'].slice(i, 1);```

Comment: Your answer unaltered doesn't return anything. If I change it to ```Array.prototype.forEach.call(this.blacklistGroupTable['blacklistGroup'], file => {console.log(file)});``` then it returns each row as it's own objects in console

Comment: yep , the first time i did a mostake in the syntax , can you screenshot the log ?

Comment: I'm a little confused on what this.splice represents and it doesn't see _id from object? https://postimg.cc/7bNw2cTJ unless id is this:            ```if (file.id === this.blacklistGroupTable['blacklistGroup']._id) {```

Comment: i've maded an update , please do like in the answer , `this` represent one file from `blacklistGroupTable`

Comment: function(this.blacklistGroupTable, index){}

Comment: about the id it is the value you got when you loged the list , you can use name also to delete

Comment: Ok I get it with the splice now I think, but I'm still having one other issue: https://postimg.cc/zLmwH5vT  If I get rid of this. it accepts it as a parameter, but I still get an error. https://pastebin.com/6XxWfF2v

Comment: That returns ```"_this.blacklistGroupTable.forEach is not a function"``` I found a solution though! ```const files = [...this.blacklistGroupTable['blacklistGroup']];
          files.splice(i, 1);```

Comment: that's good , if it's always the same name `blacklistGroup``then you won't have any problem

Comment: I appreciate the help regardless though!